# kbd formatted text overlaps normal text in a list

Tags: bug, status-completed, layout

I noticed this in a [recent post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34025/in-glitch-how-can-i-see-quickly-how-many-skills-i-have-learned/34026#34026):

[image: Narwhals! Narwhals! Swimming in the ocean!]

It doesn't seem to happen here
<kbd>It doesn't seem to happen here</kbd>

- But it does seem to happen here
  <kbd>But it does seem to happen here</kbd>

I first wrote this post up on MSO, but realised it *didn't* happen there!

Comment: I really wish kbd trimmed down the fat. The padding and borders don't tend to play nice with everything else.

Comment: I saw the same thing [in an answer of mine](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33963/madden-nfl-12-instructions/33972#33972). I had to go back and add blank lines to space things out better.

Comment: Note: mobile is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove the vertical padding from the <kbd> tag](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/remove-the-vertical-padding-from-the-kbd-tag)

Comment: @MatthewRead That's definitely related, but not a duplicate, this is a different issue.

Comment: @fredley The reason the spacing is different between the two is because the `line-height` of the `<p>` and the `<li>` tags are different. As I noted [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5414/15772) changing `display` attribute of the `kbd` pseudo-tag should solve the `kdb` tag cutting into to the line above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a while to get to this, but now it is done...

I've updated the styles of the kbd element to have `display: inline-block;`.

With you in the next build.